# Pinned memory in LibTorch

Tags: pytorch, tensor, libtorch

I might be missing something really fundamental but I couldn't find any explanation in the documentation or online

I'm trying to copy a GPU `at::Tensor` to a pinned tensor on the CPU, but once I copy it, the CPU tensor is no longer pinned. I assume it just creates a new copy of the GPU tensor and assigns it, but if that's the case, how do you copy to a pre-allocated pinned memory?

My testing code:

```
    at::Tensor gpu = at::randn({1025,1025}, device(at::kCUDA));
    at::Tensor pinned = at::empty(gpu.sizes(), device(at::kCPU).pinned_memory(true));
    std::cout << "Is Pinned: " << std::boolalpha << pinned.is_pinned() << std::endl;
    pinned = gpu.to(at::kCPU);
    std::cout << "Is Pinned: " << std::boolalpha << pinned.is_pinned() << std::endl;
```

The output is

```
Is Pinned: true
Is Pinned: false
```

This also happens with `torch::` instead of `at::`

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 using LibTorch 1.5.0 compiled from sources

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to copy GPU tensor to CPU with pinned memory? It's usually done the other way around (load data via CPU into page-locked memory in order to speed up transfer to GPU device). BTW. You can always use `torch` namespace instead of ATen's `at` as `torch::` forwards everything from `at` (which makes the code less confusing).

Comment: we have an application which runs inference on the gpu, slices it and splits it into different tensors and then we need to download it to the cpu to continue using it in other parts of the app. Since this is a real-time application, every ms counts and we try to optimize where we can, it saves us about 3 ms so we're happy :)
And thanks for the namespace comment. Good to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way, and that's using the `copy_` function

```
...
//pinned = gpu.to(torch::kCPU, true);
gpu.copy_(pinned);
std::cout << "Is Pinned: " << std::boolalpha << pinned.is_pinned() << std::endl;
```

This outputs

```
Is Pinned: true
Is Pinned: true
```

I guess it makes sense since the `to` function returns a tensor rather than manipulating. Though I would expect some variant of `to` to allow it.

Oh well, it works this way.